# Efficient way of creating an array/vector of strings and finding out the length of all strings in it

Tags: c++, arrays, string, performance, vector

I want to create a function in which I can iterate over an array/vector containing a variable amount of strings, and I need to know the length of the strings before I send them to the function. How can I achieve this in an efficient way?

I have some loose idea of the function, but how do I **efficiently** sent an array/vector of strings to it and the size of all those strings combined. For example, the function could look something like this:

```
myFunc(vector<string> s, int totalWordLength) {
    // Loop over strings in vector.
}
```

I could do something like this to create a vector of strings.

```
const char *args[] = {"12345", "678"};
vector<string> s(args, end(args));
```

But how do I then find out the size of the strings (8) in this without looping through it so that I can send it to `myFunc(s, sizeOfStrings)`?

*If you have an idea to achieve the same result, by using an array instead or something, please let me know. I'm trying to do this as efficient as possible.*

Comment: Add up the length of the strings as you receive them, or loop over the vector and add up their `size()`.

Comment: The "without looping through it" constraint makes it difficult.  Even `auto total = accumulate(s.begin(), s.end(), 0UL, [](auto acc, string a) { return acc + a.length(); });` has a loop inside of it, unless you are ignoring algorithms that loop on your behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through container (container class irrelevant)

```
const char *args[] = {"12345", "678"};
vector<string> s(args, end(args));

size_t sizOfS = 0;
for( auto& item : s )
  sizOfS += item.length();
```

Another way unites  process of filling array and calculating length:

```
const char *args[] = {"12345", "678"};
std::vector<std::string> s;
s.reserve(sizeof(args)/sizeof(args[0]));

size_t sizOfS = 0;
for( const std::string& item : args )
{
  sizOfS += item.length();
  s.push_back(item);
}
```

Regardless of what you do, cost of the process would be O(n), where `n = strings * their-total-length`. There is no other defined way, but several functions which can turn loop into one-liner. Even if define your own container that would track length of strings, its cost would have same order.

Which container to use depends on what kind of actions you expect to perform, vector got constant cost of random access to container items, but linearly increasing cost of growing its storage. list may have cheap insertion\push cost but it got sequential iterator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the lengths of all of the strings in the vector and query it often (its not a one-off thing) then you can calculate the length of the strings when they are added together and store the total with the vector.

A quick example of this with a class:

```cpp
class MyClassFoo {
public:
  std::vector<std::string> items;
  std::size_t total_item_sizes = 0;

  void addItem(const std::string& item) {
    total_item_sizes += item.length(); // Add its length to the total
    items.emplace_back(item); // Add the item to the vector 
  }
}
```

Then you can pass this object around and query it.

If you want to be more efficent pass by reference or move single use parameters. This is important with something like a `std::vector` as you probably don't want to copy all it's elements.

As an aside it is unlikely this is *actually* neccasary, unless you are trying to sum the lengths of all the strings very frequently and there are a lot of them, your bottleneck will not be iterating over an `std::vector`. Your demand for 'efficency' smells like premature optimisation. Remember the 20-80 rule (80% of your program execution time is spent running 20% of your code).

Answer (score 0):

Given your scenario, an approach could be to calculate the length of the strings at the time of construction of the vector.

One solution using a variadic template could be a wrapper like this ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/63GSuA)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct V
{
    template <typename ... T>
    V( T&& ... t ) : v{ std::forward<T>(t)... }
    {
        for ( const auto& s : v ) size += s.size();
    }

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::size_t size {0};
};

int main()
{
    const char *args[] = { "12345678", "6789", "1234", "5678" };

    V obj ( std::begin(args), std::end(args) );

    std::cout << "No. of Strings : " << obj.v.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Total Length   : " << obj.size << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
No. of Strings : 4
Total Length   : 20
```